Beartype and jaxtyping incorrectly catching Tensor type errors at runtime
I'm using torch, jaxtyping and beartype to type annotate my functions (with runtime type checking). I have used the @jaxtyped(typechecker=beartype) decorator.
I have received the following error at runtime:
jaxtyping.TypeCheckError: Type-check error whilst checking the parameters of display_features_from_tokens_and_feature_tensor.
The problem arose whilst typechecking parameter 'tokens'.
Actual value: tensor([41083,   531,   366, 31373,   612,     1,   290,   788,  3332,   866,
13], device='cuda:0')
Expected type: <class 'Int[Tensor, 'seq_len']'>.`

As far as I can tell the type of the actual value matches the expected type. Is there some nuance of beartype or jaxtyping that I am missing?
I suspected that it may be to do with the fact that my tensors were on the GPU but couldn't find any mention of this within the jaxtyped docs.
I also tried using Int64 to no avail (same error).

Could it be related to https://docs.kidger.site/jaxtyping/faq/ "flake8 or ruff are throwing an error"?
For single dimension shape checks, you might have to prepend a space to the shape string, which would be " seq_len".
